# Syntax error when parsing variable from XML within an SQL stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, xml, string

So, I'm trying to run a stored procedure within another stored procedure and parse out some XML data into a variable.  It is giving me a syntax error on the first plus sign im using to  add that variable within the XML string.    Its kinda like this:  names are changed to protect the innocent.
(SQL stored Proc:)

```
EXEC [database].some.Stored.proceddure
@variabelOne = 0
,@variableTwo = 
    '<Root>
    <r>
    <RefID>1</RefID>
    <GroupID>2</GroupID>
    <GroupFilter>' + @AnotherVariable + '</GroupFilter>
    </r>
</Root>'
```

Comment: The error is: Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: Calculate your `@variableTwo` before trying to pass it to the procedure. Also please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/11683.

Comment: please tag your rdbms

Comment: You have tagged `mysql`. You execute stored procedures with `CALL` in MySql. Are you using SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use + or CONCAT in exec. Save the string first to a variable and then call the exec:

```
declare @var_two varchar(max)

set @var_two = '<Root>
    <r>
    <RefID>1</RefID>
    <GroupID>2</GroupID>
    <GroupFilter>' + @AnotherVariable + '</GroupFilter>
    </r>
</Root>'

EXEC [database].some.Stored.proceddure
@variabelOne = 0
,@variableTwo = @var_two
```